# Complete Select Statement ELSE a defaulted value?

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a complete select statement and if no row is returned to return a row with a default value in a specific field (SQL Server)? Here's a generic version of my SQL to better explain:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(c.InjuryDate as DATE)>DATEADD(dd,-60, getdate ()) THEN b.InjuryID end) InjuryCount, a.PersonID
FROM Person_Info a
    JOIN Injury_Subject b on b.PersonID=a.PersonID
    JOIN Injury_Info c on c.InjuryID=b.InjuryID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Hospital_Record d WHERE d.PersonID=b.PersonID and d.InjuryID=b.InjuryID) --There could be multiple people associated with the same InjuryID 
GROUP BY a.PersonID

If NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Hospital_Record d WHERE d.PersonID=a.PersonID) THEN '0' in InjuryCount
```

I want a row for each person who has had an injury to display. Then I'd like a count of how many injuries resulted in hospitalizations in the last 60 days. If they were not hospitalized, I'd like the row to still be generated, but display '0' in InjuryCount column. I've played with this a bunch, moving my date from the WHERE to the SELECT, trying IF ELSE combos, etc. Could someone help me figure out how to get what I want please?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Note "generic version" in my text. Those aren't my tables, fields, or aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without an example of input and desired output, but I think this is what you are going for:

```
select 
    InjuryCount = count(case 
        when cast(ii.InjuryDate as date) > dateadd(day,-60,getdate())
          then i.InjuryId 
        else null
        end
        )
  , p.PersonId
  from Person_Info p
    left join Hosptal_Record h on p.PersonId = h.PersonId
    left join Injury_Subject i on i.PersonId = h.PersonId 
                              and h.InjuryId = i.InjuryId
    left join Injury_Info ii  on ii.InjuryId = i.InjuryId
  group by p.PersonId;
```